# indexing/slicing a 2d numpy array using the range/arange function as the argument

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range

I have a basic doubt in numpy.  I am using Python 2.7, numpy-1.9.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

For example, I initialize a 2d numpy array as `a = np.zeros((10,10))`.

I then try to index a portion of it using the range function as the indices by the following way:

`a[range(0,5),range(0,5)]`.  I get an array of shape (5,).  What I want is the first 5 rows and columns of the 2d array `a`.

When I perform `a[:5,:5]`, it seems to give me an array of shape (5,5).

Can someone explain to me why using the range function for specifying the index is failing?  I am still confused about numpy indexing even after working with it for almost an year.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: what would you expect `a[[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4]]` to give you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `range` you are using `integer array indexing` as described here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

To get the equivalent of `a[0:5,0:5]`, you have to take advantage of 'broadcasting'.  Here the 1st index is a column vector

```
a[np.arange(0,5)[:,None],range(0,5)]

In [137]: np.arange(0,5)[:,None]
Out[137]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

I could go into more detail, but you could just as well read that doc.

---

`np.ix_` is a utility that helps generate this sort of indexing arrays:

```
In [507]: np.ix_(range(0,5),range(0,5))
Out[507]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]))
```

This (5,1) array broadcasts against a (1,5) array to produce a (5,5) indexing array.

MATLAB and numpy have choose alternative advanced indexing approaches:

In MATLAB/Octave, `a([1,2,3],[1,2,3])` indexes a (3,3) block.  In `numpy`, `a[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` indexes the (3,) diagonal.

`a(sub2ind(size(a),[1,2,3],[1,2,3]))` is the Octave diagonal; `a[np.ix_([1,2,3],[1,2,3])]` is the `numpy` block.

Comment: Thank you.  I will avoid using integer arrays or range for that matter.  I wonder why they gave the ability of broadcast integer arrays instead of using them as regular slicing.

Comment: Sometimes we need to select blocks from an array, sometimes selected items scattered through it.  No need to duplicate with ranges what you just as well accomplish with slices.

Comment: This is so gross and messy. There has to be a cleaner way to do what the OP wants to do.

Comment: I edited my answer to compare the numpy and MATLAB approaches to advanced indexing.  You can make indexing a block easy, or you can make indexing items easy.  But it's hard with one notation to keep both simple.

Comment: Just want to add that R uses the MATLAB approach to indexing.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without the memory allocations of the intermediate arrays?

Comment: @Royi, what memory allocation are you worried about?  A (n,1) array can be a view of a (n,) shape, with little added memory use.

Comment: @hpaulj, When I access a NumPy array using `mA[a:b, c:d]` there is no allocation of `a:b` or `c:d`. When I use `np.ix_(range(a, b), range(c, d)` 2 arrays are allocated. I wonder if there's a trick to overcome this.

Comment: @Royi, why you use the `range` approach when you can get the same result with the `a:b` `slice(a,b)` approach?  With slices you get `basic indexing`, producing a faster `view`.  The other is `advanced indexing`, producing a `copy`.  `np.ix_([1,3,2], [5,7,8,3])` is a more realistic case for using `ix_`.  I used `ix_` and `range` because the SO was asking for a slice equivalent.  `ix_` is a convenience function that produces the broadcastable arrays shown in [507].  I'm showing how to select blocks with `advanced indexing`.